# Localization of multi style text element in Vue

Tags: html, i18n, vue.js

After following up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129480/styled-text-in-vue-interpolation), I'm thinking if there's a better/shorter way to write this text element that has part with different style, while allowing localizations:

```
<p>
    <span class="has-text-grey">{{ $store.releaseList != null ? $store.releaseList.length : 0 }}</span>
    <span> versions released</span>
</p>
```

With `vue-i18n`:

```
<p v-html="$t('downloads.releases.table.versions-total')
    .replace('{0}', '<span class=has-text-grey>{1}</span>')
    .replace('{1}', $store.releaseList != null ? $store.releaseList.length : 0)">
</p>
```

The localizable text would be `{0} versions released`.

I could set the localizable text to `<span class=has-text-grey>{0}</span> versions released`, but that would make the life of the translators (usually people without knowledge about HTML) a bit more difficult.

Is there any better built in way to add support for localizations in a multi-styled text?